# Query and Graph are not found Fuseki Info [108] 400 Error

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I am running query from the live demo (http://biohackathon.org/d3sparql/). The SPARQL endpoint is changed to the localhost endpoint built using Apache Jena Fuseki server. The RDF file is uploaded and stored in the server and the SPARQL endpoint is set. The set up for making the RDF file accessible via HTTP is basically a success and changes could be tracked through terminal.

So, I am trying to implement D3Sparkle to visualise the data. All I did so far is changing the endpoint and put my SPARQL query respectively in the D3Sparkle live demo page. However, when I try running the query, it I got this error:

```
 [2017-02-25 00:05:30] Fuseki     INFO  [108] GET /ds :: 'data' :: <none> ? query=PREFIX%20up%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.uniprot.org%2Fcore%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20tax%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.uniprot.org%2Ftaxonomy%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Froot_name%20%3Fparent_name%20%3Fchild_name%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Ftogogenome.org%2Fgraph%2Funiprot%3E%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Froot_name%20%7B%20%22Tardigrada%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Froot%20up%3AscientificName%20%3Froot_name%20.%0A%20%20%3Fchild%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%2B%20%3Froot%20.%0A%20%20%3Fchild%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3Fparent%20.%0A%20%20%3Fchild%20up%3AscientificName%20%3Fchild_name%20.%0A%20%20%3Fparent%20up%3AscientificName%20%3Fparent_name%20.%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20

 [2017-02-25 00:05:30] Fuseki     INFO  [108] 400 Neither ?default nor ?graph in the query string of the request (0 ms)
```

Does anybody had the same experience or any advices?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please post the query here in a non-encoded form?

Comment: Which version of Fuseki is this?

Comment: Unrelated: The query has "FROM" in it. That will pick a graph out of the dataset. Was that he intention? It is better done with GRAPH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is not directed to the query endpoint.  Usually that's `/ds/sparql` or `/ds/query`.

It is going to `/ds/data` which is the default for SPARQL Graph Store Protocol (GSP) operations.

The error is from the GSP handler.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it works when I changed to /ds/query :)